# Measuring the dB of a frequency after FFT

Tags: python, audio, signal-processing, fft

I have a wavfile that is read and fft'd. Sampling frequency is 22050Hz.

```
fs, y = scipy.io.wavfile.read('StarWars60.wav')
N = len(y)
yf = rfft(y)
xf = rfftfreq(N, 1/fs)
```

y is int16 and takes range [-32768,32767]
yf has abs values that are typically around 2000000

for each of the yf values, which correspond to the fft coefficient of a specific frequency at a specific sample, I'm trying to scale it to some dB measurement so that I can make comparisons across frequencies and times. It does not have to be an exact interpretation of dB, just one that is appropriately scaled (with a range from 0 to 120)

I think the rough scalings involved are:

1. taking amplitude
2. intensity  = amplitude**2
3. 'dB' = 10 * log(intensity)

I am thus doing it like

```
amp = np.abs(yf[i])
intens = amp**2
d = 10*np.log(intens)
```

but getting numbers for d like 200 for the 10000Hz range, and 300 for the 50Hz range.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "but getting numbers for d like 200 for the 10000Hz range, and 300 for the 50Hz range" Whats wrong about those numbers?

Comment: 1) use a base 10 log; and 2) add an appropriate offset.  You can put 0 wherever you want, so `d = 10*np.log(intens)/np.log(10) + offset`. Also note that`intens == 0` corresponds to -infinity dB, so you want to cut that off at some point.